# [Android]How to passing single string in AnsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a project in android which is built following MVP pattern. Everything is ok until I use AnsynTask to get data from server. I don't know why I can't passing string to method in Presenter class. 
Here is my Presenter class:

```
 public class BookingPresenter implements Serializable{
        private static final String TAG_SOAPACTION_Office = "http://tempuri.org/getOffice";
        private static final String TAG_NAMESPACE_Office = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String TAG_METHODNAME_Office = "getOffice";
        private static final String TAG_URL = "http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx";

        private static final String TAG_ID_Office = "ID_Office";
        private static final String TAG_ID_OCompany = "ID_Company";
        private static final String TAG_Street_Office = "Street";
        private static final String TAG_DistrictOffice = "District";
        private static final String TAG_City_Office = "City";
        private ArrayList<OfficeModel> arrOffice;
        IBooking iBooking = new IBooking() {
            @Override
            public void getTicketToBooking(String ticket_ID, String company, String departure, String arrival, String type, Date date, String time, Double price, String status, String phone, String services) {

            }

            @Override
            public void get_Office(ArrayList<String> arrStrOffice) {

            }
        };
        public ArrayList<String> getOffice(String IDPassenger){
            arrOffice = new ArrayList<OfficeModel>();
            ArrayList<String> arrayListAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(TAG_NAMESPACE_Office, TAG_METHODNAME_Office);
            request.addProperty("ID_Company",IDPassenger);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport=new HttpTransportSE(TAG_URL);
            transport.debug = true;
            try{
                transport.call(TAG_SOAPACTION_Office,envelope);
                SoapPrimitive data = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                String jsonText=data.toString();
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonText);

                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    OfficeModel officeModel = new OfficeModel();
                    JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    officeModel.set_ID_Office(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString(TAG_ID_Office).toString()));
                    officeModel.set_IDOCompany(jsonObject.getString(TAG_ID_OCompany).toString());
                    officeModel.set_StreetOffice(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Street_Office).toString());
                    officeModel.set_DistrictOffice(jsonObject.getString(TAG_DistrictOffice).toString());
                    officeModel.set_CityOffice(jsonObject.getString(TAG_City_Office).toString());
                    arrOffice.add(officeModel);
                    arrayListAddress.add(arrOffice.get(i).get_StreetOffice()+ ", "+
                                        arrOffice.get(i).get_DistrictOffice()+ ", "+
                                        arrOffice.get(i).get_CityOffice());
                }
                iBooking.get_Office(arrayListAddress);
                return arrayListAddress;
            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.d("JSON", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return arrayListAddress = null;
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Loi gi day",e.getMessage());
                return arrayListAddress = null;
            } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
                soapFault.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Soap",soapFault.getMessage());
                return arrayListAddress = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return arrayListAddress = null;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return arrayListAddress = null;
            }

        }
Here is interface class: 

    public interface IBooking {
    public void getTicketToBooking(String ticket_ID, String company, String departure, String arrival,
                                   String type, Date date, String time, Double price, String status, String phone,String services);

    public void get_Office(ArrayList<String> arrStrOffice);
}

Here is fragment: 
public class BookingFragment extends Fragment implements IBooking,TextWatcher {
    private TextView tvbcompany, tvbtype,tvbtime,tvbservice,tvbphone,tvbdate;
    private TextView tvbprice, tvbtotal;
    private EditText edbnumticket;
    private Spinner spn_office;

    private  String bdeparture,barriaval,bcompany,btype,btime,bservice;
    private String bID;
    private  String bdate, bphone;
    private Double bprice,btotal;
    private int bnumticket;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    private BookingPresenter bookingPresenter;

    private ArrayList<String>arrOffice;
    private ArrayAdapter<String>arrAdapterOffice;
    public BookingFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking, container, false);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


       bookingPresenter = new BookingPresenter(this);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        TicketInforModel tk = new TicketInforModel();
        //tk = (TicketInforModel) bundle.getSerializable("arrResultTicket");
        bookingPresenter.processTicketInfor((TicketInforModel) bundle.getSerializable("arrResultTicket"));

        spn_office = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spn_boffice);
       // loadDataToSpinner();
        //String a = "C01";

        tvbcompany = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bcompany);
        tvbcompany.setText(bcompany);

        tvbdate = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bdate);
        tvbdate.setText(bdate);

        tvbtime = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_btime);
        tvbtime.setText(btime);

        tvbphone = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bphone);
        tvbphone.setText(bphone);

        tvbservice = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bservices);
        tvbservice.setText(bservice);

        tvbprice = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_bprice);
        tvbprice.setText(String.valueOf(bprice));

        edbnumticket = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.et_numticket);
        edbnumticket.addTextChangedListener(this);

        tvbtotal = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_btotal);


        tvbtype = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_btype);
        tvbtype.setText(btype);

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void messages(String msg) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage(msg).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void getTicketToBooking(String ticket_ID, String company, String departure, String arrival, String type, Date date, String time, Double price, String status, String phone, String services) {
        bID = ticket_ID;
        bcompany = company;
        bdeparture = departure;
        barriaval = arrival;
        btype = type;
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        bdate = dateFormatter.format(date).toString();
        bphone = phone;
        btime = time;
        bprice = price;
        bservice = services;
        JSonOfficeAsyncTask jSonOfficeAsyncTask= new JSonOfficeAsyncTask();
        jSonOfficeAsyncTask.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void get_Office(ArrayList<String> arrStrOffice) {
        arrOffice = arrStrOffice;
    }

    public double calTotal(){
        btotal = bprice * bnumticket;
        return btotal;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (edbnumticket.getText().length() > 0){
            bnumticket = Integer.parseInt(edbnumticket.getText().toString());
            tvbtotal.setText(String.valueOf(calTotal()));
        }
    }

    public void  loadDataToSpinner(){
        arrAdapterOffice = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrOffice);
        spn_office.setAdapter(arrAdapterOffice);
    }

    public class JSonOfficeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //noinspection ResourceType
           // String abc  = params[0];
            return  bookingPresenter.getOffice(bID);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            if(result.size() > 0 ){
                loadDataToSpinner();
            }
            else{
                messages("Fail City: " + bID+ result);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try passing bID to method getOffice(), the message "Fail: + bID" is show and the bID is not null. Morever, when I try change bID by fixed string, it works perfect. I don't know what is my problem so please help me. 
p/s: so sorry if i wrong grammar or something like that, my english is not good. And I want to thanks you for reading my question.

Comment: It depends on when `getTicketToBooking` method called. explain from where you are calling `getTicketToBooking` method

Comment: getTicketToBooking is a interfaces class. I tried getting value of biD to make sure its not null.

Comment: I mean new value is assigned in `bID` inside `getTicketToBooking` right? so probably `getTicketToBooking` method is called after executing `AnsyncTask`. let me know if still not clear to you why this issue happening

Comment: Yup, I understand but how can I set it run before executing AnsyncTask ?

Comment: By moving `jSonOfficeAsyncTask.execute();` line inside `getTicketToBooking` method

Comment: I tried, but it still not working, I don't know why

Comment: Show ur updated code

Comment: I just edited,is that right ?

Comment: Means getting null in `ticket_ID` . let me know from where u are calling `getTicketToBooking` method

Comment: ticket_Id is not null, If I show message(bID) in onActivityCreated(), it will show me the value of bID. I calling getTicketToBooking method from interfaces, that is implemen in Presenter. I make sure the values in getTicketToBooking are not null. I can show it on TextView, just can not pass in AsyncTask. You can see in onPostExecute(), the value of bID is return and show on message.

Comment: After discussion with you, I think i know what is my problem. You are right, but ticket_ID is not null. My problem come to i get ticket_id value to pass method that need Company_ID =.=. Thanks you for your help.